# Find limit using Taylor's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

[image]

**Note: required to use little o**

a. ($x^2-x^4/2 + o(x^4) -(1+x^2+x^4/2+o(x^4) +1)/  (1+x^4)^{1/7}-1 $

Simplifying: $-x^4+o(x^4)-o(x^4)  / (1+x^{4/7}+o(x^4)-1$.
Taking limit we get:
$-7$.

Concerns/Confusions: Not sure what happens to little os when subtracted in numerator (know they should be different) (confused overall by this concept).  Actually not sure how to get Taylor Series of $(1+x^4)^{1/7}$, had to Wolfram Alpha it.  Could someone explain to me, how to derive it by hand.  I know it has to do with the expansion of $(1+x)$, and we use $x^4$, but the $7^\text{th}$ root throws me off. I think calculating derivatives to find the coefficients would be too hard, but perhaps this may be the only way.

b.Apparently I need a change of variable to use Taylor's Theorem.  So I set $y=1/x$.
I get:

## $\lim_{y \to 0} 1/y +\sqrt{(1/y)^2+23/y}$

=
$\sqrt{(1+23y)}+1$ /$(y)$.

Expanding numerator:
$1+11.5y+o(y)+1$/ (y).

Taking limit as $x$ goes to $0$, we get $23/2$ or $11.5$.

The actual answer, however is $-23/2$, so I am confused.  I think perhaps I should put a negative in front of the square root sign, to get the right answer?  Not too sure, could really use help. And should I do the limit $\lim_{y \to 0^-}$ instead of just $\lim_{y \to 0}$.  So approaching from left hand side?

Comment: For $(1+x^4)^{1/7}$, just use the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) $\log(1+x^2)=x^2-\dfrac{x^4}2+o(x^4)$ and $e^{x^2}=1+x^2+\dfrac{x^4}2+o(x^4)$. Therefore,$$\log(1+x^2)-e^{x^2}+1=-x^4+o(x^4).$$

On the other hand, $(1+x)^\alpha=1+\alpha x+o(x^2)$ and therefore$$\sqrt[7]{1+x^4}-1=\left(1+\frac{x^4}7+o(x^4)\right)-1=\frac{x^4}7+o(x^4).$$So$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x^2)-e^{x^2}+1}{\sqrt[7]{1+x^4}-1}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-x^4+o(x^4)}{\frac{x^4}7+o(x^4)}=-7.$$
b) $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}x+\sqrt{x^2+23x}=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac1x+\sqrt{\frac1{x^2}+\frac{23}x}=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac1x-\frac1x\sqrt{1+23x}$, where the minus sign comes from the fact that $x<0$. The previous limit be written as$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{1-\sqrt{1+23x}}x$$and, since $\sqrt{1+23x}=1+\frac{23x}2+o(x)$, you get that the limite is $-\frac{23}2$.

Answer (score 1):

a. Expansion by hand isn't so hard with a substitution.

$$\left((1+x)^{1/7}\right)'=\frac17(1+x)^{-6/7}\to\frac17$$ giving

$$(1+x)^{1/7}=1+\frac x7+o(x).$$

Then substituting $x^4$ for $x$,

$$(1+x^4)^{1/7}=1+\frac{x^4}7+o(x^4).$$

---

The straight way is indeed a little harder:

$$\left((1+x^4)^{1/7}\right)'=\frac{4x^3}7(1+x^4)^{-6/7}\to0$$

Before going further, let us spare some work by noticing that

$$(x^3f(x))'=3x^2f(x)+x^3f'(x)\to0$$
$$(x^3f(x))''=6xf(x)+6x^2f'(x)+x^3f''(x)\to0$$
$$(x^3f(x))'''=6f(x)+18xf'(x)+9x^2f''(x)+x^3f'''(x)\to6f(0).$$

From this, the development to the fourth order is

$$1+\frac{24}{7}\frac{x^4}{4!}+o(x^4).$$